# Random Page Rewrite

Tags: query, wp-redirect

I have the following code which redirects visitors to a random page on my site, but I only want certain pages randomly available. 
Can someone please tell me how I can restrict it to certain mutiple taxonomies (i.e. only Games/Films/Television)?

Many thanks

```
 add_action('init','random_add_rewrite');
 function random_add_rewrite() {
   global $wp;
   $wp->add_query_var('random');
   add_rewrite_rule('random/?$', 'index.php?random=1', 'top');
 }

 add_action('template_redirect','random_template');
 function random_template() {
   if (get_query_var('random') == 1) {
        $posts = get_posts('post_type=page&orderby=rand&numberposts=1');
            foreach($posts as $post) {
                $link = get_permalink($post);
            }
        wp_redirect($link,307);
        exit;
   }
 }
```

Comment: I would note that random ordering is extremely expensive for the database, and won't scale, even if you only ask for 1, it has to load everything into memory, reorder it randomly, then it does the query you wanted

Answer (score 1):

use this template in a single page

```
<?php 
/*
 Template Name: Random3
*/
?>

<?php



$args = array(
'numberposts' => 1,
'orderby' => 'rand',
'post_type' => 'food'
);

// get a random post from the database
$my_random_post = get_posts ( $args );

// process the database request through a foreach loop
foreach ( $my_random_post as $post ) {
  // redirect the user to the random post
  wp_redirect ( get_permalink ( $post->ID ) );
  exit;
}
?>
```

change args as you need

the link of the page will redirect the user to random post